# How do I pass a hash from commandline?

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that has a hash.

Example:

```
animal_sound = { 'dog' => 'bark', 'cat' => 'meow' }
```

I want to add 'snake' => 'hiss'

Example:

```
myscript.rb --addsound "'snake' => 'hiss'"
```

Then in my script have it add it to animal_sound.

Example:

```
animal_sound.merge! 'snake' => 'hiss' 
=> {"dog"=>"bark", "cat"=>"meow", "snake"=>"hiss"}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the whole script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'micro-optparse'

options = Parser.new do |p|

        p.option :addsound, "add sound"
end.process!

animal_sound = { 'dog' => 'bark', 'cat' => 'meow' }

if options[:add_sound]
  newsound = options[:add_sound]
  animal_sound.merge! newsound 
end

puts animal_sound
```

When I run my script I get:

```
$ bin/myscript.rb --addsound "'snake' => 'hiss'"
bin/myscript.rb:14:in `merge!': can't convert true into Hash (TypeError)
    from bin/myscript.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

SOLVED:
Using PSkocik's solution I got the script to work using `animal, sound = options[:addsound].split(' => '); animal_sound[animal] = sound`

I also used Simone Carletti's idea to simplify the CLI command.  FYI it also works if I want to pass in hash format, like `myscript.rb --addsound "'snake' => 'hiss'"`.  Of course the split has to be changed back to `split(' => ')`. I like the simpler CLI using the `:`.

Example:

```
myscript.rb --addsound snake:hiss
```

Final Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'micro-optparse'

options = Parser.new do |p|

        p.option :addsound, "add sound", default: ""
end.process!

animal_sound = { 'dog' => 'bark', 'cat' => 'meow' }

if options[:addsound]
  animal, sound = options[:addsound].split(':') 
  animal_sound[animal] = sound
end

puts animal_sound
```

Command line:

```
$ bin/myscript.rb --addsound snake:hiss
{"dog"=>"bark", "cat"=>"meow", "snake"=>"hiss"}
```

I never could get the merge to work. 
Each post was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Passing in long command-line arguments is usually a bad plan. Why not, like so many other utilities, have an argument to specify a file, or read from STDIN? Both YAML and JSON are pretty easy to read and write, even by hand, and map very cleanly to native Ruby structures. Use `YAML.load` or `JSON.load` to import them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p.option :addsound, "add sound"`

^ this makes it a flag (true or false)

What you want is make it into a switch whose value is the next argument:

`p.option :addsound, "add sound", default: ""`

^ this makes it a switch, the string value will be assigned to `options[:addsound]`

`newsound = options[:addsound]`

^ Here you need to drop the underscore and parse the string into a hash.
Eval is evil.
For example, you could split it on `' => '` and forget about quoting:

```
newsound = [ options[:addsound].split(' => ') ].to_h #and then merge it
```

(Passing the argument like so `--addsound snake:hiss` and then splitting on `':'` instead of `' => '` is another good option.)

^splitting on `' => '` should yield a two-member array. Here I put it into another array (arrays of two-member arrays are convertible to hashes) to make it convertible into a hash.

Or you do completely without merging and constructing another hash:

```
animal, sound = options[:addsound].split(' => ')
animal_sound[animal] = sound
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As with Simone Carletti's code, I am getting the following error: `undefined method \`split' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: That's why you should choose my response. :D

Comment: I've edited it to make it hopefully more easy to understand. Read the top of my answer, or for TL;DR: "you need to add the `default` part to the `p.option` line to turn it from a flag (boolean) to a switch (value is the next argument).

Comment: OK... I got it to work using your `animal, sound = options[:addsound].split(' => '); animal_sound[animal] = sound` Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I did try to upvote.  Apparently I don't have enough 'reputation points" yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to keep the CLI interface detached from the underlying implementation. In fact, you may decide to switch the script in the future from Ruby to another language, and you don't really want to change the way the code is invoked.

My suggestion is to pass a serialized value, for example

```
myscript.rb --addsound snake:hiss
```

In the code, simply decompose the content and merge it.

```
if options[:add_sound]
  animal, sound = options[:add_sound].split(":")
  animal_sound.merge!(animal => sound)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and helpful response.  I see the logic in your code, but I am getting the following error: `undefined method \`split' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)`  I have googled for an answer but no answers, that I can understand and apply.  Any insights?

Comment: I see onebree's answer shows me that `options[:addsound]`
is evaluating as true.  That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**In regards to your error**

Notice the line `if options[:add_sound]`. That basically evaluates to `if true`. You are getting your error because you are setting `newsound` to `true`, and trying to merge a Boolean into a hash. To my knowledge, the `.merge` only works like so: `hash1.merge(hash2)`.

**Passing command line argument**

Rather than passing the argument `"'snake' => 'hiss'"`, I suggest making this a comma-delineated list, like so: `"snake,hiss"`. From there, in your `if options[:add_sound]` block, you can split the string into an array, using a comma as a splitter. Finally, rather than using `.merge`, you can add your key:value as you normally would for any hash in Ruby. `animal_sound[arr[0]] = arr[1]`.

Mind you, this method will work best with a single key:value pair. I am sure you can submit multiple pairs, but you would need to (by this method) split into more arrays by an additional character(like `/` maybe).